# Webpack [contenthash] parse in files

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I will do versioning via hashing. And this with Webpack.

Content of: webpack.config.js

```
...
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/dist'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
},
...
```

webpack generate some files, i think its okay, its a hash...
`app.d471b97fd69a6837f5bf.js`

In my index.html file must replace the filenames to, i do it with "replacer-contenthash-webpack-plugin" Plugin for Webpack. It used the `loaderUtils.getHashDigest(buffer)` do generate a hash. But its not the same its generate this 174d0b0d04495cf7a970 hash.

Content of: index.html
`<script src="dist/app.174d0b0d04495cf7a970.js"></script>`

how can i fix it? I dont no how webpack generate the hash with [hashcode]. Its not specified.

i have tried, to specified contenthash digest, length and function:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/dist'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    hashFunction: "md5",
    hashDigest: "hex",
    hashDigestLength: 32
},
```

and specified the used Webpack extension `getHashDigest()` so:

```
getHashDigest(buffer, "md5", "hex", 32)
```

=>
`app.54949ecc3046a8e7e56e8d9875970ca2.js`
but index.html different :(
`<script src="dist/app.174d0b0d04495cf7a970e84cc9a96cdb.js"></script>`

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The webpack plugin you are using (replacer-contenthash-webpack-plugin) is not very reputable, it's only getting around 200 downloads a week.

Check out the HtmlWebpackPlugin, it does the same thing and is getting around 13 million downloads a week.

The docs are straightforward and hopefully will sort your problem.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin